# Validate text for opened braces in text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core

How can I detect wrong braces in text? I have text with variables surrounded by “{{” and “}}”. And I want to find out if there is text like "{varname}} or {{varname or {{more than one word}} in text". I have a document, and I need pattern to find errors. No I have pattern

```
string pattern = @"^[^{}]*(?:\{(?>[^{}]+|\{(?<Depth>)|\}(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*$";

TextSelection[] textSelection2 = wordDocument.FindAll(new Regex(pattern));
```

But in result I have just text that don't have problems with braces and I need to have strings with wrong braces

Comment: This is the perfect application for a simple parser rather than a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool StringBalanced(string s)
            {
                //It will return true in the absence of any bracket. Change as needed.
                Dictionary<char, char> pairs = new Dictionary<char, char>
                {
                    { '{', '}' }
                };
                Stack<char> brackets = new Stack<char>();
                foreach (char c in s)
                {
                    if (pairs.ContainsKey(c))
                    {
                        brackets.Push(c);
                    }
                    else if (pairs.ContainsValue(c))
                    {
                        if (brackets.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (pairs[brackets.Peek()] == c)
                            {
                                brackets.Pop();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return brackets.Count > 0 ? false : true;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @insane_developer!